# Peripherals with Great Mac Compatibility

Tags: hardware-recommendation, compatibility, peripheral

What peripherals do you use on your Mac that really work well? It seems like most things (especially mice and keyboards) don't work all that well, even if they claim compatibility. I'm looking for **things that work as well on a Mac as they do on a PC**.

So, community, **what Mac peripherals do you use that 'just work', and work all the way?**

Please post answers as wiki, as I'm not looking for a particular piece of hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Logitech Mice](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice)**
I have been very happy with high-end Logitech mice. In particular the [VX](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/428/165?osid=9&softwareid=659).

Comment: You don't find their control center software a little clunky? I have the RX Revolution, and while I LOVE the mouse, I think their control panel is extremely awkward to work with. I feel pretty much exactly the same about their Harmony One universal remote I just bought. GREAT device, CRUMMY setup software UX.

Comment: I only use it once to set things up, then mostly ignore it. It's functional, like most of Apple's control panels.

Answer (score 2):

**[Razer Mice](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/DisplayCategoryProductListPage/categoryID.35208800)**

Many of their mice are fully Mac-compatible (I use the [Naga](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169418900)). Macro running and recording works perfectly, and they can be very complex (if you want). These are the only mice I've seen that work like this on a Mac.

Comment: My Razer Mouse also works well, even without the drivers installed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to know your background for the statement that "most things (especially mice and keyboards) don't work all that well"

In the 10+ years that I've been using Macs compatibility has been *better* than on PC.  Recently this has been excellent.

For cameras and printers (Epsom and Canon) I've never had to install drives for them to work with the OS, iPhoto or Image Capture.  Recently Image Capture has identified my old scanner and works better than Canon's own software at grabbing information from that.

The only peripherals I've **had** to install install software for are mice that have greater than the default number of buttons or esoteric functions (like wacom tablets).  And even then the basic functions worked out of the box.

In fact, these days, if a peripheral doesn't work out of the box on my Macs, then I get more than a bit worried that it'll cause me grief down the road - normally at the next OS update.

Comment: To name one thing: Almost all gaming mice and keyboards are not Mac compatible, or at least not all the way (especially macros).

Comment: Fair enough - but I think that Macros and extra buttons fall under the esoteric functions mentioned in my comment. :)  I wouldn't expect those to work in Windows without installing specific drivers.

Answer (score 0):

**[Matias Keyboards](http://www.matias.ca/)**

Specifically the [Tactile Pro](http://www.matias.ca/tactilepro/). Designed to the same specs as the best keyboard Apple ever made. Worth ever penny.

Comment: Nuts. Forgot to make it wiki. Can a mod do that please?

Comment: It already is, all answers to wiki questions are automatically made wiki

Comment: I have both a Matias Tactile Pro and an Apple Extended Keyboard II. There's no comparison; the Matias was clearly designed by someone who'd only heard third-hand reports of the wonders of the AEKII and never seen (much less used) one himself. I hated that thing with a passion that only grew over time, and was thrilled when I got a Griffin iMate so I could go back using the best keyboard any company has ever made. Oh, and Matias also has horrible customer support as well. Do Not Recommend.

Comment: @Dori: you're making me curious about the authentic AEKII -- might try hunting one down.